# Adding a second search for a specific content type

Tags: 7, search

I am currently trying to build out a Video-oriented component on a longform article based site, and one of the requirements call for a Video segment/block that can be placed on any page, and it has a search bar that loads any videos with similar titles.

I know that Drupal includes search, and it can be granulated to a specific content type. But I was wondering if there was any way I could implement a separate search function that inherits the existing search logic, and search for content of this specific content type. Is it as simple as altering the logic inside the search form with hook_form_alter, or are there more intricacies involved?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if I was in your case I will think about views and if the website is that heavy I will create apachesolr  view so I keep it simple flexible.